# Cognito Forms: Lookup Value

Tags: cognito-forms

It is possible to lookup values based on the value entered in a field?

e.g. I am trying to deign a form for staff to submit overtime claims - I would like them to be able to enter their payroll number / staff code and the form to display their name and hourly rate in separate fields.

I have tried using the If Then Else statement but this is cumbersome.  I would like to retrieve values from a lookup table as if using a vlookup statement in Excel.

Answer (score 2):

At this time, Cognito Forms does not have the ability to reference external data. They are, however, currently working on this feature. You can follow the progress of this feature on their [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/vKfb0oVP).